# API returns array of JSON for only one result

Tags: sql, json, node.js, api

Currently working on an API which given an address returns information about is. Some of the rows in our tables are duplicates, however being as there is over 15 million I cant go and find the duplicates. Instead I have opted to use

```
    var query = `SELECT TOP 1 * from my_TABLE where..conditions`;
```

This ensures that only one row of the duplicates are returned.
The problem is when this is sent back as a JSON it comes as an array with one object.

In the Server.js file

```
    // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();
        // query to the database
        request.query(query, function (err, result) {

            if (err) {
                console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err);
                res.send(err);
            }
            else {
                    res.send(result)
            }
```

Returns this:

```
 [{
     Address:'our info'
   }]
```

is there a way to have it respond with

```
{
 Address:'our info'
}
```

Comment: There surely is - just don't return an array of objects but an object.

Comment: What is your suggestion to achieve that?

Comment: Not sure what your question means. You have provided literally no code and want a certain answer.

Comment: So how about `res.send(result[0])`?

Answer (score 0):

Because from DB you've get list of object anyway, even there is only 1 item.

It works as you expected when you try to return `json` with the first element of your `array`.

Comment: So is there a better way to make that query from the DB, to ensure I only get one row

Comment: @Peterjamen you already have a query that returns a single row

Comment: In term of specific query like this, which is known as you will have only one 1 item, it good enough to you function like `result.getFirstObject()` to return what you want.